# Replicate Webbrowser Save Page As function in C#

Tags: c#, webclient

I'm looking for a method that replicates a Web Browsers Save Page As function (Save as Type = Text Files) in C#.

Dilemma: I've attempted to use WebClient and HttpWebRequest to download all Text from a Web Page. Both methods only return the HTML of the web page which does not include dynamic content.

Sample code:

```
            string url = @"https://www.canadapost.ca/cpotools/apps/track/personal/findByTrackNumber?trackingNumber=" + package.Item2 + "&LOCALE=en";

            try
            {
                System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

                using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                {
string content = client.DownloadString(url);
}
}
```

The above example returns the HTML without the tracking events from the page.

When I display the page in Firefox, right click on the page and select Save Page As and save as Text File all of the raw text is saved in the file. I would like to mimic this feature.

Comment: Headless browser required.

Comment: "only return the HTML"    only? What else did you want returning? Look into '.net render html' and then maybe scrape that rendering for text.

Comment: use a web browser control to render the page first, then copy the html text

Answer (score 0):

If you are scraping a web page that shows dynamic content then you basically have 2 options:

1. Use something to render the page first. The simplest in C# would be to have a WebBrowser control, and listen for the DocumentCompleted event. Note that there is some nuance to this when it fires for multiple documents on one page
2. Figure out what service the page is calling to get the extra data, and see if you can access that directly. It may well be the case that the Canadapost website is accessing an API that you can also call directly.